# Virtualhost en VPS de DigitalOcean no funciona

Tags: vue.js, apache2, ubuntu-server

El problema es algo complejo de explicar, aunque tal vez para ustedes sea algo muy sencillo, pero intentaré explicarme bien y proveer toda la información de la que dispongo.

**Problema:**
Se esta usando un servidor básico en DigitalOcean con SO Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, con 2.4.29. Dentro de este servidor hay dos proyectos, uno hecho con el framework processmaker, y otra página hecha con VueJS.

Dentro de la carpeta de sites-available se crean dos archivos de VirtualHost para cada uno de los proyectos, configurados de la siguiente manera:

Proyecto de processmaker(clinica_muriel.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName clinica.todoen1.store
#ServerAlias clinica.todoen1.store

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/clinicaMuriel/workflow/public_html/

<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverRide none
</Directory>

<Directory  /var/www/html/clinicaMuriel/workflow/public_html>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
   AllowOverRide none
   Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
   Order allow,deny
   allow from all
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /app.php [QSA,L]

   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
   </IfModule>

</Directory>
```

Proyecto de VueJS(minimarket.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>   
ServerName todoen1.store
#ServerAlias todoen1.store
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/marketplace_todoenuno/frontend/frontend/
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Posterior a esto se habilitan estos dos archivos anteriores y se reinicia el servicio de apache de la siguiente manera:

```
a2ensite clinica_muriel.conf
a2ensite minimarket.conf
sudo service apache2 reload
```

Para confirmar el estado del servidor apache, se ejecuta este comando (sudo service apache2 reload) y obtenemos esto como respuesta:

```
 apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2022-08-09 23:44:52 UTC; 18min ago
  Process: 2362 ExecStop=/usr/sbin/apachectl stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2619 ExecReload=/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 2371 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2387 (apache2)
    Tasks: 6 (limit: 1150)
   CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
           ├─2387 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2623 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2624 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2625 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           ├─2626 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
           └─2627 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Aug 09 23:44:52 bosatzu systemd[1]: Stopped The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug 09 23:44:52 bosatzu systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Aug 09 23:44:52 bosatzu systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug 10 00:03:19 bosatzu systemd[1]: Reloading The Apache HTTP Server.
Aug 10 00:03:19 bosatzu systemd[1]: Reloaded The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Pero al momento de acceder desde un navegador, tanto el dominio, como el subdominio dirigen al proyecto de processmaker nada más y no encuentro la manera de resolverlo.

El dominio y subdominio esta en godaddy y se configuro ambos con redireccionamiento permanente a la IP del servidor de DigitalOcean, al momento de hacer un ping de ambos desde una terminal, efectivamente ambos estan apuntando a la IP correcta.